# When can you use "adjective + cookie" to mean person?

Tags: expressions

I've seen people use things like "smart cookie" or "strong cookie" when referring to intelligent or strong people, respectively, and I was wondering when and which adjectives you can use in these "constructions", or if you can use any adjective you want.

Comment: I've never heard 'strong cookie'.

Comment: _Cookie_ is a diminutive. That's one reason why _strong cookie_ sounds odd. Cookies are also small, sweet, and made for the privileged, often as a reward for good behavior. The implication of _smart cookie_ or _sharp cookie_ is someone who can manage well, even without optimum resources. There is often some hint of illegality.

Comment: I've mainly heard/read "tough cookie".

Comment: @JohnLawler Thanks, that's really useful.